# RunSpacePool rebooting computers does not record success

Tags: powershell, runspace

I'm working on a script that will reboot a list of servers at a later time using the below script scheduled in Task Scheduler.

The script uses RunSpacePools to process multiple servers but what seems to happen is my script fails to record the successful reboot.

I checked a server rebooted using this script, and found an event ID 1074 from USER32 which logs the Shutdown/Restart event **but the log I create for record keeping says Reboot Failed.**

I'm just not sure how to begin troubleshooting this problem.  Any assistance is appreciated!

```
param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$InputServerList)

#Script block for runspaces

$ScriptBlock = {
 Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$server)
 $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

    Try{
$LastReboot = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $server -LogName system | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq '6005'} | Select -ExpandProperty TimeGenerated | select -first 1

Restart-Computer -ComputerName $server -Force

#New loop with counter, exit script if server did not reboot.
$max = 60;$i = 0
 DO{
    IF($i -gt $max){
        [PsCustomObject]@{
             "Server" =  $server
             "Status" = "FailedToReboot!"
             "LastRebootTime" = "$LastReboot"
             "CurrentRebootTime" = "FailedToReboot!"
          }#end custom object

            $subject="Warning: $server Did not Reboot!  Please Check!"

            #$SendTo = <Email List>

$body = @"
 LastRebootTime = $LastReboot

 Script waited 10 minutes for $server to reboot.
 "@

#Send-MailMessage <details>

    exit}#exit script and log failed to reboot.
    $i++
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
}#end DO

#At this point, server went offline.  Script waits 10 minutes for server to come online.
While (Test-path "\\$server\c$")

$max = 60;$i = 0
 DO{
 IF($i -gt $max){
        [PsCustomObject]@{
             "Server" =  $server
             "Status" = "FailedToComeOnline!"
             "LastRebootTime" = "$LastReboot"
             "CurrentRebootTime" = "FailedToReboot!"
          }
$body = @"
 LastRebootTime = $LastReboot

 Script waited 10 minutes for $server to come back online, please investigate.
 "@

$subject="Warning!!!!: $server Did not Come Online!  Please Check!"

#Send-MailMessage <details>

    exit}#exit script and log failed to come online.
    $i++
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
}#end DO
While (-not(Test-path "\\$server\c$"))

$CurrentReboot = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $server -LogName system | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq '6005'} | Select -ExpandProperty TimeGenerated | select -first 1
    [PsCustomObject]@{
             "Server" =  $server
             "Status" = "RebootSuccessful"
             "LastRebootTime" = $LastReboot
             "CurrentRebootTime" = "$CurrentReboot"
              }

}#End Try.

Catch{
 $errMsg = $_.Exception.Message.ToString().Trim()
 #"$server : Failed with $errMsg"
        [PsCustomObject]@{
             "Server" =  $server
             "Status" = "FailedToReboot!"
             "LastRebootTime" = "$errMsg"
             "CurrentRebootTime" = "FailedToReboot!"
          }#end custom object
 }

}#end script block

#Define computers to work with.

$Computers = Get-Content $InputServerList


#Create Runspace pool
$RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(30,30)
$RunspacePool.Open()
$Jobs = 
 foreach ( $Computer in $Computers )
  {
 $Job = [powershell]::Create().
        AddScript($ScriptBlock).
        AddArgument($Computer)
 $Job.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool

 [PSCustomObject]@{
  Pipe = $Job
  Result = $Job.BeginInvoke()
 }
}

Write-Host 'Working..' -NoNewline

 Do {

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

} While ( $Jobs.Result.IsCompleted -contains $false)

Write-Host "Finished."

$(ForEach ($Job in $Jobs)
{ $Job.Pipe.EndInvoke($Job.Result) }) |
 Export-Csv -Path "D:\Scripts\Reboot-Async-Results.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
#clean up runspace
$RunspacePool.Close()
$RunspacePool.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I added a flag that is set for rebootCheck true or rebootCheck false in the `[PSCustomObject]` output.  The last thing the script does it check this flag and perform a final check that determines if the Reboot Failed email is needed.

```
$counter = 0
do{$counter++

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
 IF($counter -ge 600){#"Waited too long"
        [PsCustomObject]@{
             "Server" =  $server
             "Status" = "FailedToReboot!"
             "LastRebootTime" = "$LastReboot"
             "CurrentRebootTime" = "FailedToReboot!"
             "ReCheckReboot" = $true
          }#end custom logging object
        exit
 }#end if.
}#end do loop. #Break RebootSentWait continues script on next line.

until (-not (Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Count 1 -Quiet))
```

Then the variable, named `ReCheckReboot` is checked for true/false using an IF statement before the script ends.